# ffmpeg re-encode rtsp stream to H264 ONLY if stream is not H264

Tags: ffmpeg

I have 100 rtsp cams streaming to my server, which does RTSP --> HLS for web viewers.

Most (about 90) rtsp cams are H264, but some can't be configured back to HEVC for some reasons.

Is there a command in FFMPEG to:

1. re-encode to H264 (preferrably using libx264) if stream is not H264
2. just do copy-frame if stream is already H264
   ?

ps: it's run using python/node with no-shell mode, so I'm not sure if bash-redirects/pipes work

tried ffmpeg commands

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You have to query the codec first. You may use FFprobe for getting the video codec. Example: `ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mp4`

Comment: ok... so it's not possible with one-liner command   I was hoping to not use ffprobe because it might mean longer start-time (server has hundreds of cams)